# How to open and modify png in C++

Tags: c++, png, jpeg

How to, display png (generally images beside .bmp) get it's depth, color(r,g,b) of a particular pixels(x,y) and how to change exactly one pixel then save the image. I could not find any simple example of that. Please show any sample

**No 3rd party libraries, any please.**

Comment: have you looked at [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) and/or [libjpg](http://www.ijg.org/) or are you trying to do this entirely on your own, or are you using some other libraries?

Comment: I want to use only internal libraries no 3rd party.

Comment: You *might* be able to find some code demonstrating how to do that for PNG, but I'd be a little surprised if you could find it for JPEG. JPEG is complex enough that few people re-implement it from the ground up, or even consider it reasonable to try.

Comment: Providing sample code is difficult. You're asking us to implement deflate compression here (PNG's are compressed.) This is a silly thing to ask for, IMO.

Comment: also, in what kind of software are you trying to do that - on a mobile device, on linux, windows, or where? You want to use "only internal libraries" - of what?

Comment: Why are 3rd party libraries not allowable? Every image format has its own way of storing data so there is no simple answer to cover all. Some are compressed (lossless or lossy), some use palettes rather than RGB, and many other variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PNG format is relatively simple, but not so simple as BMP. For one thing, it includes ZLIB compression. To encode/decode it you either need to use a PNG library like [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) plus a [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) library. If you don't want to use "third party" libraries (use only the standard libraries) you'd need to write quite a lot of code; you'll end rewriting the libpng/zlib libraries, almost; I doubt you'd really want to do that.

I myself wrote a  PNG coder/decoder in Java/C# ([PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/)), but I relied on external ZLIB libraries (it's included in standard Java JRE)

Answer (score 2):

Note that C++ isn't Java, or Python or somesuch. C++ internal libraries are mostly concerned with raw data handling, and leave more specific features to third parties. That is the very *concept* of C++ (and C, too).

Asking for a "purely internal" implementation of PNG (or "generally pictures beside .bmp") is, therefore, downright silly. You would need a different function for each specific picture format, usually including decompression, and since third-party libraries for that specific purpose are *readily* available, asking people to re-implement them is a bit... weird.